# Loop through columns with group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data set

```
age salary gender
44  3000   M
32  4555   F
45  6000   M
50  4200   F
43  5000   F
23  1700   M
```

I want to loop through each column and get max/min value for age/salary group by gender using numby, i did this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numby as np
data = pd.read_excel("file")
var = ["age","salary","gender"]
dat = data[var]
column_list = dat.columns.values.tolist()
resAll = pd.DataFrame()
for col in column_list:
            minn = np.min(dat[col])
            maxx = np.max(dat[col])
            res = [[str(col), ' '],
                   ['min', str(minn)],
                   ['max',str(maxx)]
                  ]
            resNum = pd.DataFrame(res)
            resNum.columns = ['0','1']
print(resNum)
```

output

```
0       1
age
max     50
min     23
salary  
max     6000
min     1700
gender 
max f
min m
```

I want to be able to do that grouped by gender! any help ? like this, knowing that number of columns is not fixed size.

```
value       male   female      
age
max         45     50
min         23     32
salary  
max         6000   5000
min         1700   4200
```

Answer (score 2):

dataframes have a method `describe()` which outputs the descriptive statistics for each column. It can be used after grouping by a column to break down the stats for each group. If you only need the min and max, you need to drop the rest of stats.

```
df = df.groupby('gender').describe()
```

if you want to keep just the min and max and drop the rest, use drop.

```
df = df.drop(columns=['count', '25%', '75%', '50%', 'mean', 'std'], level=1, axis=1)
```